# Swift doesn't recognize recursive call to function, thinks it's a local variable

Tags: ios, swift

I am following along with the Stanford Swift course on iTunes.  I am in lesson 3 where the professor writes a recursive function to evaluate a stack of operators and operands.

Here is the code as the professor has typed it:

```
class CalculatorBrain
{
   private enum Op {
       case Operand(Double)
       case UnaryOperation(String, Double -> Double)
       case BinaryOperation(String, (Double, Double) -> Double)
   }

   private var opStack = [Op]()

   private var knownOps = [String:Op]()

   init() {
    knownOps["×"] = Op.BinaryOperation("×", *)
    knownOps["+"] = Op.BinaryOperation("+", +)
    knownOps["-"] = Op.BinaryOperation("-") { $1 - $0 }
    knownOps["÷"] = Op.BinaryOperation("÷") { $1 / $0 }
    knownOps["√"] = Op.UnaryOperation("√", sqrt)
   }

   func pushOperand(operand: Double) {
      opStack.append(Op.Operand(operand))
   }

   func performOperation(symbol: String) {
      if let operation = knownOps[symbol] {
        opStack.append(operation)
      }
   }

   private func evaluate(ops: [Op]) -> (result: Double?, remainingOps: [Op])
   {
    var remainingOps = ops
    if !remainingOps.isEmpty {
        let op = remainingOps.removeLast()
        switch op {
        case .Operand(let operand):
            return (operand, remainingOps)
        case .UnaryOperation(_, let operation):
            let operandEvaluation = evaluate(remainingOps)
            if let operand = operandEvaluation.result {
                return (operation(operand), operandEvaluation.remainingOps)
            }
        case .BinaryOperation(_, let operation):
        // code snipped
        }
    }
    return (nil, ops)
   }
}
```

I get a compiler error but he doesn't.

The error I get is on the line `let operandEvaluation = evaluate(remainingOps)`.  I get the error "Use of local variable 'evaluate' before its declaration"

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?  It's supposed to be a recursive call to the function `evaluate`, but instead the compiler thinks `evaluate` is a local variable.

I am using Xcode 6.4 on OS X 10.10.4

Thanks!

Comment: Did you forget a closing bracket?

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed the closing }.  It was missing in my post but not in my code.  The error still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error, too.

However, I fixed it by adding my bracket to the **if clause** several lines below that error.

Comment: Brrrr, same here: a missing bracket in the bottom of that call made the function inivisible. Therefor the compiler thought it would be a property

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `}` to close:

```
if let operand = operandEvaluation.result {
```

And the the `switch` is not exhaustive, you need to add the missing `case .BinaryOperation`.

Comment: Thanks.  Both of those were typos in my post but they are fixed in my code.  I've updated the post to reflect that.  I still get the compiler error.

Answer (score -1):

There was a bracketing typo after all.  Sorry, and thanks for the assistance.